# codeception, cest classes and usersteps

Tags: codeception

I get the impression the codeception documentation is outdated.

I have Cept files working with a usersteps definition file that I use for things like login calls.

Due to complexity, I'd love to use Cest classes instead, but I can't get them to recognize my Usersteps. Here's an example:

```
<?php

/*
 * @guy TestGuy\UserSteps
 */
class ViewPagesCest {

public function testViewCharacter(TestGuy $I) {
    $I->loginToCharacter('admin', 'admin', 'Alice Kepler');

    $target = $I->grabFromRepository('BM2SiteBundle:Character', 'id', array('name' => 'Carol Stanis'));
    $I->amOnPage('/en/character/view/'.$target->getId());
    $I->see($target->getName());
}
```

}

I get, of course:

> [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method
>   TestGuy::loginToCharacter

because loginToCharacter is defined in a usersteps file. The same stuff as a Cept file works just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use docblock (T_DOC_BLOCK) to place @guy annotation, but you use comment (T_COMMENT).

Just add second star at beginning of your comment:

```
/**
 * @guy TestGuy\UserSteps
 */
class ViewPagesCest {
```

Comment: http://leehblue.com/how-to-use-stepobjects-in-cest-classes/ A better explanation of how it should be done

Comment: Link above was very helpful